# Cannot compile Cuda 7.0 sample

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-14.04

I installed CUDA 7.0 as described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#install-source) on Ubuntu 14.04. I look at matrix mul example, if I start executable file `matrixMul` that runs, but if I try to compile it gives me error on libraries. 
i.e 
`user@Mars:~/Documenti/Bello/NVIDIA_CUDA-7.0_Samples/0_Simple/matrixMul$ nvcc matrixMul.cu
matrixMul.cu:36:30: fatal error: helper_functions.h: File o directory non esistente
 #include <helper_functions.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.`

Comment: It seems you did not use the makefile. That's why includes are missing. Did you try to compile with `make`?

Comment: I tried to compile with 'make' and it runs. thank you so much @havogt

Comment: @adry_b89:please add that as an answer (it's ok to answer your own question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by trying to compile the sample using nvcc without the correct compiler options, rather than with the supplied makefile. Using the makefile allowed the compilation to work successfully.